# Query with a "With" Clause inside a For Loop Cursor of DB2 PL SQL

Tags: for-loop, cursor, db2, with-clause, sql-pl

I have a very complex query that includes a "With" clause. This query works fine when executed on the DB2 Client. But if the same query is used inside a For Loop Cursor of a PL SQL stored procedure it does not work. On trying to apply the stored procedure to the database, it gives a syntax error as shown below.

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "AS" was found following "col5 )
```

The for loop is as shown below.

```
FOR records AS cursors CURSOR FOR
  (
    WITH
    temp1
    (
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    )
    AS 
    (
        SELECT
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM
        table1
    )
    WITH
    temp2
    (
        col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
    FROM
        table2
    )
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, co7, col8, col9, col10
    FROM temp1, temp2
)
DO
    -- Do Something here.
END FOR;
```

Can you please help solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you executing the statement in a loop?  SQL is usually much better at working in sets.

Comment: No specific reason as such. The data returned by the SQL query will be modified inside the loop. There are various transformation rules that i have to apply and i thought having results processed record by record gave me a lot of control over the data. Hence used the method as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, the `FOR` statement is incorrect; it should refer to a previously declared cursor:

```
...
CURSOR mycur IS WITH ... SELECT ...;
...
FOR rec IN mycur LOOP ...
```

Second,the query

```
WITH temp1 ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 ) AS ( 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table1 
) 
WITH temp2 ( col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 ) AS ( 
  SELECT col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 FROM table2
```

is invalid and would never run by itself, so your claim that it executes in the CLP is untrue.

Comment: With the kind of For Loop that i have used here, DB2 implicitly creates a cursor on which i can loop over. I need not explicitly declare it. With the query that i have written i was trying to narrow down on the problem rather than writing the exact query. There is of course a select following the with clause in my above query. Please check my edit and let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: The query is still invalid, and the `FOR` statement syntax is still wrong. You may want to check the manual for the correct syntax of both.

Comment: I have used the same For Loop construct as given in the below link. And it does work without any problems. Is there still something wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198577/how-to-get-db2-9-7-cursor-value-in-for-loop-where-returned-value-is-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this thing working. The solution was fairly simple. It was to remove the braces enclosing the query as shown below.

```
 FOR records AS cursors CURSOR FOR 

    WITH
    temp1
    (
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    )
    AS 
    (
        SELECT
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM
        table1
    )

    WITH
    temp2
    (
      col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
    )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
    FROM
        table2 
    )
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, co7, col8, col9, col10
    FROM   temp1, temp2
DO
    --  Do Something here.

END  FOR  ;
```

I am not really sure why it happens like this. It works just fine for any other normal query without a WITH clause in it.